# How do I install MPlayer and MEncoder in Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Tags: 18.04, mplayer, mencoder, dvd-backup

I am trying to make use of OGMrip, a dvd encoder. I get an error every time that states I need to install MEncoder. How do I go about doing that?

I have tried updating and this does not resolve the issue. Do I need to manually download something from the terminal? Also this program is dependent on ogmtools mplayer mkvtoolnix oggenc lame and faac.

I am not sure if I have these packages. How can I tell?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the program packages are in the repository universe.

`faac` is in the repository multiverse.

I did not find any package `oggenc`, but the package `vorbis-tools` contains the program `oggenc`.

So the following command line should work, when you have the repositories universe and multiverse. Universe is already there when you have installed Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ogmrip
```

If `ogmrip` is not fixing its dependencies, you can help it by installing the following packages,

```
sudo apt install mplayer mencoder mkvtoolnix vorbis-tools lame faac
```

---

A general way to install several multimedia tools is to install the meta-package 'restricted-extras'.

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I have multiverse installed already, however when I attempted to install ubuntu restricted extras it froze at 36%. Also the package configuration window... I cant find any way to click on the OK and I imagine I must accept this agreement. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help. @sudodus

Comment: Also I have an error message i just noticed It reads: an error occured please run package manager from right click menu,but when I right click there is no package manager. Or i can run the package manager using get apt in terminal. Do I dare close the terminal now to do that? It is still running but stuck at 36%

Comment: @MikePeterson, 1. Please edit your original question to show the exact error messages. In order to render the output to the terminal as 'code', please indent each such line 4 spaces; 2. When problems, you can try with `sudo apt install -f` and then `sudo apt update` and the install commands again.

Comment: I do not know the original error message. And I fail to understand why I should edit my question.  I do not get an error message anymore perhaps because I have used ubuntu software updater. However I attempted to install ubuntu restricted extras again and  it says i have newest version 66 and I get an additional output of:  0upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.  Do I have to upgrade them somehow with command codes?  I have no idea what you mean by "in order to render the output to the terminal as code". Also I don't understand the last sentence. Thank you. @sudodus

Comment: @MikePeterson, Are you able to install `ogmgrip` now? If not, please run the command line `sudo apt install -f` and then `sudo apt update` and after that `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ogmgrip`

Comment: You misunderstand. I have already installed ogmrip months ago I am having trouble getting it to work properly. I thought it was because of package dependancies. However I am not getting anymore error messages but the program does not work properly it suddenly stops after 10% of backing up a DVD. Thank you for your help. @sudodus

Comment: @MikePeterson, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I know how to install program packages, but I have no experience of the `ogmgrip` program. So I cannot give you any specific help. But a general tip would be, that there might be a read error 'at 10%' of the DVD disk. You can use `ddrescue` (installed by `sudo apt install gddrescue` and learned via `info ddrescue`) in order to get the best possible image of the DVD disk. Maybe that image can be read and processed properly by `ogmgrip`.